# Combine multiple .wasm files into one single .wasm file

Tags: javascript, webassembly, zlib

Can we combine multiple (more than 10) **.wasm** files into a single **.wasm** file?

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the answer you're looking for, but here it is.

I do not know of a tool that combines wasm files into one. However, it is possibly to do this manually (and possibly automate it).

You will need [`wasm2wat`](https://github.com/WebAssembly/wabt) to convert `.wasm` files to `.wat` files, which are an intermediary representation of wasm (like assembly is for machine code).

Each `.wat` file has the following strucure:

```
(module
  ;; contains code (functions, types, etc.)
)
```

So your output `.wat` file should look like this:

```
(module
  ;; code from the other .wat files, excluding the `(module )`
)
```

So, you strip the `(module` at the beginning of your input files and the `)` at the end of those files. Then, you paste that code into the output file.

This has one downside, however; you will also copy duplicate functions, so you'll have to filter those out.

Hope this at least helps a little.

Answer (score 1):

There was a project for that, but apparently, it was considered as [not used enough](https://github.com/WebAssembly/binaryen/issues/2174).

You cannot "just" copy/paste the WebAssembly textual serialization of two or more modules and expect that to work. The different objects inside (functions, globals, etc.) are accessed (called/get/set) by indexes not just by names. You would have to fully process the modules and merge them IF the [multiple memories proposal](https://github.com/WebAssembly/multi-memory/blob/main/proposals/multi-memory/Overview.md) was operational. But it is [not yet ready](https://webassembly.org/roadmap/).

Answer (score 1):

As Nikolay mentioned, the lack of 'multiple memories' support is the main hurdle in doing that reliably.

The rest of the wasm module "primitives" -- types, funcs, tables, globals, elems, datas, imports, exports -- can be merged by avoiding conflicts using a relatively simple, but fully static renaming/renumbering scheme. I'm saying relatively simple, because this entails inspecting and modifying the func byte code so it refers to the new indices after renumbering.

One of the reasons this works is there's already support for multiple tables, so the code in "module A" can use the original table indices, the code in "module B", when merged, can be patched to use "original table index + (count of tables in mod A)", the code in mod C will use "original table index + (count of tables in mod A + count of tables in mod C)", etc. *(The other reason this works is because it's not possible to define new tables at run-time -- that is, the count of tables in each module is static and known in advance)*

'start' (entry point) is a bit different -- you'll have to pick one.

'memory' is a problem though. The merged module will still only have just a single 'memory' that needs to somehow be shared between all the pre-merge modules. Generally, this is not possible, because the func logic in each module assumes it has full control over the entire memory space.

That being said, *it's possible to come up with a scheme* for merging 'memory' that might work **for most situation**. (let's ignore [memory64 proposal](https://github.com/WebAssembly/memory64) for now) There are several constraints though:

- the module being merged should not contain the `memory.grow` instruction, or if it contains it then the memory definition should also specify a max size, e.g. `(memory 1 16)`.
- the combined total memory usage of all modules being merged should not overflow the memory32 size limit, i.e. 4 GiB.

Given these constraints, the 'trick' relies on the fact that memory `load` and `store` instructions allow for a const immediate offset arg, e.g. `(i32.load8_u offset=25)`. So, if memory use of each module is known (the constraints ensure that), the byte code of load/store instruction of each module being merged could be modified by adding a synthetic `offset=` to each instruction so that it doesn't overlap with the memory 'address space' of all modules merged so far (existing `offset=` will simply be increased by that amount)

Answer (score -1):

The [Binaryen](https://github.com/WebAssembly/binaryen) project has the tool `wasm-merge`. It was removed from the project some time back (as [described in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73687316)), but after seeing more use cases in the wasm GC space, this was reconsidered ([#5709](https://github.com/WebAssembly/binaryen/pull/5709)), and a new version of the tool was made available since May 2023.

```
wasm-merge module1.wasm module1 module2.wasm module2 module3.wasm module3 -o merged.wasm --rename-export-conflicts
```

This might not be entirely seamless however. `wasm-merge` relies on support for multiple memories and multiple tables in the WebAssembly runtime, so as to avoid the problems described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73715262/1233251). Few runtimes support this at the time of writing ([according to the roadmap](https://webassembly.org/roadmap/), Chrome 120 & others behind experimental flags). One can try calling `wasm-opt` on top of the output file with the option `--multi-memory-lowering` to narrow it down to a single memory, although your mileage may vary here.