# Why my Blazor Wasm app is downloading 90 .wasm files every page refresh?

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, webassembly

I have a Blazor 8 Wasm app that is working fine, but in every page refresh/navigation it tooks many seconds to load. Looks like the web assembly files are not being cached.

When I look in the network tab, 90 files are being downloaded every time:
[image: 90 .wasm files in chrome network tab]

I thought the .NET runtime would be download only on the first access when using WebAssembly.

What could it be?

These are the packages I have installed:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: status is 304 not modified - maybe its already loaded?

Comment: Are you deploying the debug version or the release version?

Comment: Do you have caching disabled?

Comment: @AndrewMorton Release

Comment: @sommmen so it's working as intended? thanks

Comment: @Diego I thought that maybe the release version would package them all up into one download. Apparently not: [Combine multiple .wasm files into one single .wasm file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73248579/1115360).

Comment: @Lex I don't remember to modify anything related to cache. Everything is on the default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like someone in the comments mentioned, the status code is 304, meaning 'Not Modified'. This means the browser intercepted it and sent the cached version back instead of re-requesting it from the server.